# Visualising directed hyperedges in network graph Python

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization

I'm trying to visualise a multi-edge directed graph, with hyper-edges. I've looked into python NetworkX, I'm starting with the directed graph, which can basically give me this:

[image]

But I would like to visualise my edges combined (since they are a kind of "bundle", with multiple source vertices, and one destination vertex).

Like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a sample edgelist?

Comment: I don't have an edge list created yet, what kind of edge list should I create to get the result of the second picture?